# how to find complement of a dataframe with respect of another df?

Tags: join, pyspark

I wanna find all rows in df1 which dose not contain and `id` from df2. In pandas I can do it by the following code

```
df1.merge(df2, on='id', how = 'outer' ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
```

how I can do it in pyspark?

Comment: I think `anti join` will suffice your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`left_anti` join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join)

###### `df1`

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'),
    (1, 'c'),
    (2, 'd'),
    (2, 'e'),
    (3, 'f'),
], ['id', 'col'])

+---+---+
| id|col|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  1|  b|
|  1|  c|
|  2|  d|
|  2|  e|
|  3|  f|
+---+---+
```

###### `df2`

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'),
    (1, 'c'),
], ['id', 'col'])

+---+---+
| id|col|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  1|  b|
|  1|  c|
+---+---+
```

###### `left_anti` join

```py
df1.join(df2, on=['id'], how='left_anti').show()

+---+---+
| id|col|
+---+---+
|  2|  d|
|  2|  e|
|  3|  f|
+---+---+
```